# Python: Convert to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

How do I convert below json to a dataframe?

```
{
    "stocks": "SEPOWER,ASTEC,EDUCOMP,KSERASERA,IOLCP,GUJAPOLLO,EMCO",
    "trigger_prices": "3.75,541.8,2.1,0.2,329.6,166.8,1.25",
    "triggered_at": "2:34 pm",
    "scan_name": "Short term breakouts",
    "scan_url": "short-term-breakouts",
    "alert_name": "Alert for Short term breakouts",
    "webhook_url": "http://your-web-hook-url.com"
}
```

I am receiving data in this format/structure from a webhook. This is a sample data.

I tried to normalise. Also tried many things but no luck. New to Python